# Identifying a font from a set of diagrams

Tags: font-identification

What is the font used in these diagrams? I tried searching, but can't find exact one.

www.identifont.com gives me "Chalfont Light" as a result, but this is not the font used in diagrams.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to say for sure at that size, but it appears to be House Industry's Neutraface:

http://www.houseind.com/fonts/neutraface

Comment: I think you are right! Everything matches.

Comment: @VividD glad to help! Also, if you think that's the match, please don't forget to mark the answer as being correct.